# Element disappearing

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/ddGHz/1004/

```
//html

<div id = "anglereturn"/>
<div class="box"></div>

//js, jquery

var box=$(".box");
var boxCenter=[box.offset().left+box.width()/2, box.offset().top+box.height()/2];

$(document).mousemove(function(e){    


var angle = Math.atan2(e.pageX- boxCenter[0],- (e.pageY- boxCenter[1]) )*(180/Math.PI);     

box.css({ "-webkit-transform": 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});    
box.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});
box.css({ 'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'});

$("#anglereturn").text(angle);

});

//css

.box{
    background-color: black;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;

    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
}
```

in this fiddle it has a small black box that rotates to face the mouse pointer, i added another element that shows what current angle the object is at, but once the mouse is moved into the area, it disappears and only the angle shows, how would i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.box` element is a child of `#anglereturn`. I noticed that you've tried to make the element self-closing, but this is an invalid syntax (for divs, anyway) in HTML. You'll want to properly close your element with its own `</div>` tag.

Because the page is dismissing the invalid HTML, it is representing your HTML as:

```
<div id="anglereturn">
    <div class="box">
</div>
```

This means that, when changing the text for `#anglereturn`, you are essentially removing the box element altogether, since you are modifying its parent value.

You'll want to add another enclosing `</div>` tag to your `#anglereturn` element:

```
<div id="anglereturn"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```